# Get the second-to-last occurence of a character from a string

Tags: python-3.x

How do I get the second to last occurence of a character in a string?
I want to use it to get `aaa` from `www.example.com/example/abc/aaa`

Comment: I've noticed you haven't accepted any answers... check this out to see how it works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

I like regular expressions:

```
import re
p = re.compile('a')
all_positions = [oMatch.span() for oMatch in p.finditer(sText)]
second_last_position_span = all_positions[-2]   
second_last_position_start_index = second_last_position_span[0]
```